# Definite article: "use ‘the’ with names" vs "use ‘the’ with the names"

Tags: articles

Can someone explain why the author used `the` before noun `names` in these cases

- Use *the* with **the** names of hotels & restaurants, unless these are named after a person
- Use *the* with **the** names of famous buildings, works of art, museums, or monuments.
- Do not use *the* with **the** names of meals
- Do not use *the* with **the** names of languages
- Do not use *the* with **the** names of individual mountains, lakes, and islands

but not in these...

- Use *the* with names of geographical areas, rivers, mountain ranges, groups of islands, canals, and oceans.
- Do not use *the* with names of countries (except for the special cases above).
- Do not use *the* with names of shops
- Do not use *the* with people's names.

(https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/definite-article/)

Comment: Hello, Buffy. Can you explain the sense you intend for 'only' here, please?

Comment: It's indefinite.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting question, touching on a point of syntax I do not see in
my grammar references. Let us explore.

Intuitively, a native English speaker recognizes that **the** before
**names** is optional in each of these cases. (The last sentence is
different syntactically, and is not addressed in this answer.) Here are
some similar constructions where **the** is likewise optional:

- [The] leaders of democratic nations are usually persuasive public speakers.
- [The] shorelines of lakes are sometimes highly developed.
- [The] covers of graphic novels often feature a dramatic scene from the story.

In each of these cases, as well as the cases in the question, **the** is
only optional because the noun it modifies is also being modified by a
prepositional phrase — “of languages”, “of democratic nations”, “of
graphic novels”. Without such a prepositional phrase, we would be
referring to names, shorelines, etc. in general, and the use of **the**
would be incorrect (unless an earlier sentence had specified what names
or shorelines we are referring to). With such a phrase, **the** can be
used or omitted, and the sentence sounds correct either way. Why?

I think it is because the noun phrase in these cases is a sort of
hybrid. The noun can be viewed as a generic noun (names, leaders,
shorelines, covers in general), which cannot take **the**; but it can
also be viewed as one that, having been specified (names *of languages*,
shorelines *of lakes*), does take **the**. Consider these phrases:

- Covers of graphic novels
- The covers of graphic novels

The first usage seems more generic: covers of all graphic novels,
considered as a class. The second seems more specific: which covers?
*these* covers.

As I said, a most interesting question, and one that I was unable to
find addressed in my reference materials. I did find some material
online addressing similar issues:

- [Use (or non-use) of articles before abstract nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104023) (see top answer)
- [Q: Optional use of 'the' referring to "daily life of" vs. "daily life as"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/391067) (unanswered)
- http://www.everythingenglishblog.com/?p=502