# Is the definite article necessary before "treatment" in these sentences?

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article, zero-article

Can I use the definite article before the word "treatment" in a generic sense? If not, what's the difference in the meaning of these sentences?

1. Several therapeutic agents have been evaluated for (the) treatment of Covid-19, but none have yet been shown to be efficacious.
2. The optimal dose and duration of (the) treatment of COVID-19 with Remdesivir are unknown.
3. The cost-effectiveness of (the) treatment of Covid-19 was calculated.
4. Individualizing (the) treatment of patients is being considered.

Which one is grammatically correct?

5. The use of Remdesivir for (the) treatment of Covid-19 was approved.
6. The use of Remdesivir **for** a treatment of Covid-19 was approved.
7. The use of Remdesivir **as** a treatment of Covid-19 was approved.
8. They have used Remdesivir for (the) treatment of Covid-19.
9. They have used Remdesivir for a treatment of Covid-19.
   They have used Remdesivir for a treatment of Covid-19.

Comment: In all your examples the definite article is *optional* - and including it or not makes no difference to the meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Definite article: "use ‘the’ with names" vs "use ‘the’ with the names"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/165728/definite-article-use-the-with-names-vs-use-the-with-the-names)