# Definite articles_plural and uncontable nouns_generalization

Tags: grammar

I am learning about definite articles. I came across a thread: [Definite article: "use ‘the’ with names" vs "use ‘the’ with the names"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/165728/definite-article-use-the-with-names-vs-use-the-with-the-names/165729#165729)

That says "the" is optional in these general sentences below:

```
[The] leaders of democratic nations are usually persuasive public speakers.
[The] shorelines of lakes are sometimes highly developed.
[The] covers of graphic novels often feature a dramatic scene from the story.
```

If so, when talking about a type of something in general, I can use either version. Right?
Could you tell me the subtle difference between the version with "the" and without "the" of sentences above?

As I can see, the examples above talks about plural noun (leaders, shorelines, covers, . I also wonder if this can applies with uncountable noun when making a general statement. Is "the" also optional in these sentence below:

1. (The) development of cities has become the first concern for
   governments in the word.
2. (The) contamination of water has become severe nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer  "The development of cities has become ...", but "City development has become..."

I don't think it is an error to omit the in "Development of cities has become..." But the sentence seems more fluent with it, perhaps because "of cities" specifies a particular type of development.

And not "The city development", since this article seems to refer to a determined city, not a determined type of development.